# Is there a better way to add headers to CSV file using Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Is there a more efficient way to add headers to CSV file rather than hard-coding them?

`$Importfile = Import-csv $path$filename -header H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, H7 #add headers to csv file`

Comment: you can use Get-Content to load the 1st line of a file, split by the delimiter, count the items, and then use that to generate the header row.

Answer (score 7):

here's one way to auto-generate a header line for a CSV file that does not have one. it counts the items in the 1st line of the file to generate the header row. [*grin*]

```
$FileName = "$env:TEMP\Alex_-_Headerless.csv"
$Delimiter = ','

#region >>> create a headerless CSV file to work with
#    remove this section when you are ready to do stuff for real
$HeaderlessCSV = @'
1001, Jon, Smith, Anvil Inspector
2002, Bob, Archer, Bow Builder
3003, Mike, Carter, Wagon Designer
'@ | Set-Content -LiteralPath $FileName
#endregion >>> create a headerless CSV file to work with

$ColumnCount = @((Get-Content -LiteralPath $FileName -TotalCount 1).Split($Delimiter)).Count
$HeaderLine = foreach ($Index in 1..$ColumnCount)
    {
    'Col_{0}' -f $Index
    }

$InStuff = Import-Csv -Delimiter $Delimiter -Header $HeaderLine -LiteralPath $FileName

$InStuff
```

output ...

```
Col_1 Col_2 Col_3  Col_4          
----- ----- -----  -----          
1001  Jon   Smith  Anvil Inspector
2002  Bob   Archer Bow Builder    
3003  Mike  Carter Wagon Designer
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex - you are most welcome! glad to help a tad now & then ... [*grin*]